# Increase a char value by one

Tags: java, android, eclipse, string

I have an app with an `EditText` and a button named "forward". All I want is just when I type "a" in the `EditText` and click the button, the word "b" to be typed in the `EditText`, "c" if pressed again and so on. I have tried:

```
value = edt.getText();
edt.setText(value + 1);
```

But that of course will print the initial string followed by the number "1". Any ideas? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Tested and works**

All letters can be represented by their [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) values.

If you cast the letters to an `int`, add 1, and then cast back to a `char`, the letter will increase by 1 ASCII value (the next letter).

For example:

`'a'` is `97` 
`'b'` is `98`

So if the input was `'a'` and you casted that to an `int`, you would get `97`. Then add 1 and get `98`, and then finally cast it back to a `char` again and get `'b'`.

Here is an example of casting:

```
System.out.println( (int)('a') ); // 97
System.out.println( (int)('b') ); // 98
System.out.println( (char)(97) ); // a
System.out.println( (char)(98) ); // b
```

---

So, your final code might be this:

```
// get first char in the input string
char value = et.getText().toString().charAt(0);

int nextValue = (int)value + 1; // find the int value plus 1

char c = (char)nextValue; // convert that to back to a char

et.setText( String.valueOf(c) ); // print the char as a string
```

Of course this will only work properly if there is one single character as an input.

Comment: Your code will work even if multiple characters are there in the edit text.

Comment: @amalBit Yes but it won't work properly. If I enter `xaq` the output will be `y`. And if nothing is entered, it will break. It's fine, just not perfect.

Comment: Can't you add `1` to a char directly?

Comment: @user2357112 Like [this](http://ideone.com/QysiWv)? Yes you can, but only because the cast is just done automatically for your at that point. I just prefer to explain the entire thing. In other languages, it might not compile if you add incompatible types (char and int).

Comment: `char` is a numeric type, like `byte` or `short`, and the same (annoying) conversion happens with those types (even if both operands are byte, char, short, or whatever).

Comment: @user2357112 You call it a conversion, but that is the same as a cast. Simply put, you can't compare two values of different type (I think). One is casted to be the same type as the other. I understand what you're saying, but I see it this way: `'a' + 1` could be interpreted as `'a' + '1'` or `97 + 1`. Either way, one type is casted to the other. But yes, because `char` is a numeric type, it will end up being `97 + 1`.

Comment: @user2357112 Actually, I just tested this and I guess you're probably right: http://ideone.com/0467ev Although I still feel that what I've said is correct. I'm not too sure. I know `char` is a numeric type, but there still must be casting to similar types. Hmmm, oh well.

Answer (score 10):

A simpler way would be:

```
char value = edt.getText().toString().charAt(0);
edt.setText(Character.toString ((char) value+1));
```

Here the `value + 1` adds the decimal equivalent of the character and increments it by one.. Here is a small chart:

[image]
[image]

Whats happens after 'z'? ... it wont crash.. [see here for the full chart.](http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/ascii.html).

Comment: There's a small problem with this. Attempt to find it. Hint: it happens to be one of your "shortcuts".

Comment: I think i got it now.. ?

Comment: Nope that doesn't matter. Your output will always give you the *same* value as the input. Why?

Comment: Why would you use an error-prone preincrement rather than just `value + 1`?

Comment: @user2357112 I did not know that preincrement is error-porne. If you could point me to that direction. I will correct myself.

Comment: It's prone to exactly the error you made - mixing up pre- and post-increment - and prone to errors where you forget that you had an increment operator in the middle of an expression and try to use the variable for the original value.

Answer (score 6):

Try this one

```
String convertString = getIncrementStr("abc");
public static String getIncrementStr(String str){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(char c:str.toCharArray()){
        sb.append(++c);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert the text value (character) to the ascii value, then increase it, not just the text.

```
value = edt.getText().toString();
int ascii = (int)value;
edt.setText(Character.toString ((char) ascii+1));
```

Comment: Tried it too and gave missmatch and cannot cast issues =/ thanks tho

Comment: @GopalRao Correct, I fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

```
String value = edt.getText();
edt.setText(value + 1);
```

If the above is your code, then what you are doing is concatenating a 1 to the end of your `value` string.  Thus, a button click would alter the displayed text from "your text" to "your text1".  This process would continue on the next button click to show "your text11".  The issue is really a type error.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
edt.setText(Character.toString((char)(edt.getText().charAt(0) + 1)));
```