# Increment char by another char in a string

Tags: java, encryption

I am working on an encryption/decryption program for a project. For the encrypt method, user inputs a key (all lowercase no space) and all the letters in the file are shifted by the value of each letter in the key (a = 0, b = 1, c = 2 etc.).

Example:
Key = abc

File: words in a file

Encrypted file: wptdt kn b himg

'w' was increased by 'a' (0) so it stays 'w'.

'o' was shifted by 'b' (1) so it increased by 1 letter to 'p' etc.

After the last letter in the key is used, the key goes back to the first letter. Also, spaces are ignored.

I am currently confused on how to increment a letter by each letter in the  key.

```
public static String encryptLine(
```

Any help would be appreciated! 
Thanks

Comment: share your input and expected output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Increase a char value by one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22574768/increase-a-char-value-by-one)

Comment: You're skipping spaces in your "encryption"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

[Source Code](http://ideone.com/cilKET)

```
public static String encrypt(String plainText, String encKey) {
    StringBuilder encryptedText = new StringBuilder();
    char[] encArray = encKey.toCharArray();
    int encArrayLen = encArray.length;
    int cnt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < plainText.length(); i++) {
        if (plainText.charAt(i) != ' ') {
            char c = (char) (plainText.charAt(i) + (encArray[cnt] - 'a'));
            encryptedText.append(c);
        } else {
            encryptedText.append(plainText.charAt(i));
            cnt=cnt-1;
        }
        cnt++;
        if (cnt == encArrayLen) {
            cnt = 0;
        }
    }
    return encryptedText.toString();
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to contact you outside of this website? Or can you notify me if you get this notification

Answer (score 0):

**Try using this code**

```
public static String encrypt(String k,String l){
        String ans="";
        int index=0;
        for(int i=0;i<l.length();i++){
            if(l.charAt(i)==' '){
                continue;
            }
            ans=ans+Character.toString((char)((int)l.charAt(i)+((int)k.charAt(index)-97)));
            if(index==k.length()-1){
                index=0;
            }else{
                index++;
            }
        }
        return ans;

    }
```

Comment: Is there a way to contact you outside of this website? Or can you notify me if you get this notification?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String encryptLine(String key, String line) {
    final StringBuffer encryptedLine = new StringBuffer();

    IntStream.range(0, line.length()).forEach(i->{
        int nonSpace = ((int) line.chars().limit(i+1).filter(j -> j == ' ').count());
        encryptedLine.append( line.charAt(i) == ' '? line.charAt(i): (char) (key.charAt((i - nonSpace) % key.length()) - 'a' + line.charAt(i)));
    });

    return encryptedLine.toString();
}
```

Text:words in a file-->wptdt kn b himg

However, it is just a quick hint. For project using, more checks are expected.